# Gazebo 9 Contact Plugin Not Working

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have followed the tutorial in this link http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor for contact sensor plugin. However, it seems not just plugin, the sensor itself is not working in gazebo 9.7 . Is there anyone make it running in the gazebo 9?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/22600/gazebo-9-contact-plugin-not-working/) by [dogukan_altay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9243/dogukan_altay/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For anyone who encounters the same issue. The bumper sensor should be attached to the link with the desired collision. Sensor should not be attached to a dedicated link.

---

Originally posted by [dogukan_altay](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/9243/dogukan_altay/) with karma: 3 on 2019-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0